# Display stacked x-axis text field hierarchy instead of drill down in Power BI

Tags: text, charts, powerbi, hierarchy, x-axis

I'm new to Power BI & am sure there's a simple answer, like a setting or something...
Need to display all fields stacked in x-axis at once, instead of having to drill down through any layers.  In excel pivot table it does this automatically (please click for pic)

[image: pivot chart]

But I'm struggling to figure this out in Power BI, seems like only date hierarchies display neatly, how can I show tidy hierarchies on the x-axis with text fields? (please click for pic)

[image: Power BI stacked x-axis]

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this arrow in the upper right corner of every visual (chart)
[image]

To cancel concatenation of  x-axis labels: Format/ X Axis / Concatenate labels OFF
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your response Andrew... yes true that kinda concatenates labels to show all the levels at once, it's just visually unappealing - looks messy & confusing for users... Was hoping to find a way to have the fiscal year & fiscal quarters written only once, instead of having "FY + FQ + Category" for every entry... It's such basic functionality in Excel, hard to believe MS wouldn't include it in PBI   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Then you can do this: Format/ X Axis  / Concatenate labels OFF (I will add a screenshot)

Comment: OMG - thank you thank you thank you!  I had tried that before with no luck, but this time I created a new chart, & made sure the "concatenate labels" = ON to start... then when I had all my fields in place BEFORE turning labels off - it worked!!!!!!!!!  So very much appreciate your help, I knew it had to be a newbie, obvious, thing - but couldn't get it to work - Order of Operations!! :))

Comment: @5flatKat You're welcome:) If my answer solved your issue please mark it as the correct answer to positively close the question.